# Mac Cornerstone (SVN client) how to connect to https:// with certificate

Tags: macos, svn, authentication, visualsvn-server, cornerstone

We use a **VisualSVN Server** (Windows) server at work. It uses a `https://` connection with a **SSL certificate**. On our Windows (7 and 8) workstation machines we use TortoiseSVN to connect. On Windows I couldn't get a connection to this SVN server (at first) using a regular SVN username and password, got SVN auth error:

`Error during context: An error occurred during authentication`

### On Windows we got it working

So we figured out we need to supply a (Windows) credential to this domain name. Like suggested on this website:

http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/Issue-with-basic-authentication-td95075.html

On Windows we opened `Control Panel > Credential Manager` and added a new `Windows credential` to a network address (website): **URL of our SVN server** and a (domain) **username** (which is the SVN username) and my **password**.

**Now this worked on our Windows workstations**, we can connect to the SVN server with a supplied (Windows) credentials (supplied in Windows Credential Manager).

### On Mac (not yet)

In Cornerstone we get a similar error:

`Error running context: The requested authentication type(s) are not supported`

Now we need this to work on our (Maverick) Mac's in Cornerstone (Mac SVN client). I've searched the net and found various articles, even on Zennaware's (Cornerstone) own support site explaining **how to add the certificate** to the SVN connection within Cornerstone:

http://zennaware.com/cornerstone/helpbook/pages/getting-started/client-certificates.html

But the above on Mac is 'step 2' ... I need a way to (like on Windows) to first create the credentials (step 1).

Now I know it must be done in Mac's **KeyChain Access** program. In this KeyChain Access program I tried to generate a certificate using the **Certificate Assistant**. But I'm **unable to generate certificate for an internet address** (our svn server) and **provide my own username and password** for this SVN server.

I've played around with **OpenSSL** on the command-line to somehow 'save' the SSL certificate from our SVN server (for import into KeyChain Access program), but I **can't provide my username and password**.

Cornerstone SVN Mac client needs a certificate (from KeyChain Access) with a **public and private key**. Like you see in their screenshots on their support site.

On Mac; how do I (generate?) the certificate or credentials (like on Windows Credential Manager) for a specific SVN server address and providing my own SVN username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely unrelated to client-side certificates / HTTPS at all.

1. On Windows machines that are in the same AD domain as VisualSVN Server, you can authenticate without any additional actions ([via Integrated Windows Authentication / Single Sign-On](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/)).

   If you are not in the same AD domain as VisualSVN Server or you need to authenticate under another AD user account, you must use [Windows Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-credential-manager) to specify user account's credentials. (lol, it looks like that [my support instruction](https://serverfault.com/a/408830/107134) helped on [the mailing list](http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/Issue-with-basic-authentication-td95075.html)).
2. No certificate setup is required on OSX machines. The instruction on Zennaware's website is irrelevant to VisualSVN Server. You have to either join the OSX machine to your AD domain and login under the AD domain user account or enter domain credentials to some OSX password store (unfortunately I'm not really familiar with OSX so no step-by-step instruction here).

   The other way to login from OSX machine is to enable Basic Windows authentication on VisualSVN Server and enter user account's credentials when you attempt to access a repository hosted on VisualSVN Server.

   BTW, make sure to run the latest available Subversion client on OSX.